# Data movement from SQL on-premise to SQL Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have migrated my database schema to **SQL Azure**, but I have huge(millions) data records to be migrated please suggest me an approach to move data

Approaches I have tried.

1. **SQLAzureMW** tool (but it takes 14 hours time, its not feasible for me)
2. Import export on SQL server(even this is taking time)

Any other approaches ..need help..!!

Comment: Take a look at Alexandre Brisebois's bulk insert technique: https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/using-sqlbulkcopy-to-insert-massive-amounts-of-data-into-windows-azure-sql-database/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For large datasets you usually have to take a more imaginative approach to migration!

One possible approach is to take a full data backup. Ensuring that transaction logs are committed and cleared at the same time.

- upload, or use [Azure Import / Export](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-import-export-service/) to get the backup into Azure blob storage
- syncronise your transaction logs with Azure blob storage
- Create an Azure SQL database, import backup
- replay transaction logs
- Keep in sync with transaction logs until you are ready to switch over.

Answer (score 0):

If 14 hours using SQLAzure Migration Wizard and your database is Azure compatible, you have 4 other choices:

- export locally to BACPAC, upload BACPAC to Azure, and import BACPAC to Azure
- export BACPAC directly to Azure and then import BACPAC to Azure
- Use SSMS migration wizard with the most recent version of SSMS (includes a number of functional and performance enhancements)
- Use SQL Server transaction replication - see additional requirements for this option. This last option enables you to incrementally migrate to SQL DB and then when SQL DB is current with your on-premise database, just cut your application(s) over to SQL DB with minimal downtime

For more information, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate/#options-to-migrate-a-compatible-database-to-azure-sql-database